# What is the meaning of the parameter 3 in the given numpy statement?

Tags: numpy

The following is a numpy statement.

```
np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
```

In the above statement what does 3 stand for?

Comment: `512` arrays with each array having `512` rows and `3` columns.

Comment: simply do `print np.zeros((5,5,3), np.uint8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result will be a 3d array, of shape `(512,512,3)`.  You can name the dimensions what is convenient, or suits the application.  The numbers suggest a 512x512 image, with 3 values (RGB) per pixel.  The `np.uint8` `dtype` is consistent with that.

Strictly speaking the expression has 2 parameters, a `tuple` and a `dtype` object class.  The `3` is part of that shape tuple.  You will reference the dimensions by number in subsequent `numpy` code.  `arr.shape[2]` will return `3`, and `arr[:,:,0]` will be all the `R` values of the image (if that is the correct interpreation).